# When i run my app for the first time and give permissions it doens't load the songs

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

The problem i have is that when i run my app for the first time, it doesn't load the data in my fragments, only when i close and then open it the songs shows.
How can i solve this?

I have 5 tabs which contain arraylists that hold the song data and display them with a custom recyclerview adapter.

Check permissions and setupViewPager are inside my MainActivity.java

Then i made separate Tab classes ( Tab1.java, Tab2.java, etc...)

Problem is that after the permissions are granted it only show my viewpager layout, but it doesn't display the recyclerview with all the songs.

It only works if i quit the app or if i switch tabs.

**Check permissions**

```
// Permission read-write storage, read phone-state
private void checkUserPermission() {
    Log.d("TAG", "checkUserPermissions: asking for user permissions!");
    String [] permissions = { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE};
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), permissions[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), permissions[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), permissions[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        setupViewPager();
        }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, permissions, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestcode, @NonNull String[]
        permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestcode){
        case 123:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                setupViewPager();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkUserPermission();
                break;
            }
        default:
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestcode, permissions,
            grantResults);

}
```

**setupViewPager**

```
private void setupViewPager() {
    //TabLayout
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Songs"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Albums"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Artists"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Genres"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Playlist"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

**TAB: here i display all songs**

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
    recyclerViewSongs = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSongs);
    activeSongTab1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.activeSongTab1);

    albumIvBottom = rootView.findViewById(R.id.albumIvBottom);
    tvCurrSongTitle = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvCurrSongTitle);
    tvCurrSongArtist = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvCurrSongArtist);

    Main.musicList = Main.songs.songs;

    // Connects the song list to an adapter
    // (thing that creates several Layouts from the song list)
    if ((Main.musicList != null) && (! Main.musicList.isEmpty())) {
        AllSongsAdapter allSongsAdapter = new AllSongsAdapter(getContext(), Main.musicList);
        recyclerViewSongs.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerViewSongs.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewSongs.setAdapter(allSongsAdapter);
        Log.i(TAG, "List is not empty");
    }else{
        Log.i(TAG, "List is empty");
    }

    recyclerViewSongs.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnItemClickListeners(getContext(), new OnItemClickListeners.OnItemClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Clicked position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            playAudio(position);
            //Fetch current song details
            tvCurrSongTitle.setText(Main.musicList.get(position).getTitle());
            tvCurrSongArtist.setText(Main.musicList.get(position).getArtist());

            //Fetch album art activeSong
            //loadAlbumArtBottom();
        }
    }));

    activeSongTab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activeSong = new Intent(getContext(), SongActivity.class);
            startActivity(activeSong);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
 public class AllSongsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllSongsAdapter.SongHolder>{
private LayoutInflater songInf;
private Context context;

private ArrayList<Song> musicList;

public AllSongsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Song> musicList) {
    super();
    this.musicList = musicList;
    this.context = context;
    songInf = LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

public static class SongHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvSongTitle,tvArtistName;
    ImageView albumIv;
    public SongHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvSongTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongTitle);
        tvArtistName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtistName);
        albumIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.albumIv);
        //tvIndex = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvIndex);

    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public SongHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
    View view = songInf.inflate(R.layout.song_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new SongHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SongHolder holder, final int position) {
    //holder.tvIndex.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", position));

    Song currentSong = musicList.get(position);

    String title = currentSong.getTitle();
    if (title.isEmpty()){
        holder.tvSongTitle.setText("<Unknown>");
    }else{
        holder.tvSongTitle.setText(currentSong.getTitle());
    }

    String artist = currentSong.getArtist();
    if (artist.isEmpty()){
        holder.tvArtistName.setText("<Unknown>");
    }else {
        holder.tvArtistName.setText(currentSong.getArtist());
    }

    Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
    Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, currentSong.getAlbumID());

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(albumArtUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_album)
            .error(R.drawable.no_album)
            .resize(220,220)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.albumIv);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return musicList.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


}
```

**TabsAdapter**

```
public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
int numberOfTabs;

public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.numberOfTabs = NumberOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new Tab1();
        case 1:
            return new Tab2();
        case 2:
            return new Tab3();
        case 3:
            return new Tab4();
        case 4:
            return new Tab5();
        default: return null;
    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numberOfTabs;
}
}
```

Comment: Is your onRequestPermission result working when you give the permissions..??

Comment: @RohitSharma yes, but the only problem is that at first install/start of the app it doesn't show the songs, but when i close the app and then open it again it works.

Comment: @RohitSharma I have MainActivity where i ask for the permissions and setup the ViewPager and in my fragments (Tab1.java, etc...) i have an arraylist<Song> which hold songs information and with an adapter i display those songs. But now i need to find a way to initialize that adapter when the user gives permission.

Comment: do the tabs appear when you allow the permission..??

Comment: @RohitSharma yes everything appears except the recyclerview that displays all the songs and when i close the app and open it again it shows the recyclerview.

Comment: @RohitSharma Any idea how i can fix this? Is there a way to initialize fragments after i granted permission so that it sets the adapter and displays the recyclerview? I know that the problem is that it stops after checking for permission and only initializes the adapter when i close the app or switch tabs.

Comment: Can you share the TabsAdapter class

Comment: @RohitSharma added it at the bottom of the post

Comment: It seems fine your Share your activity

Comment: @RohitSharma Check permission and setupViewPager in my post are the only things in my MainActivity and in onCreate() i call checkUserPermissions()  Everything is at the top of my post.

Comment: Then you have done everything right just if the REQUEST_CODE==123

Comment: @RohitSharma Ok, but how do i fix the problem that when my app starts for the first time it directly shows all songs? Now it only shows the tabs and viewpager but no songs.

Comment: You need to learn how to debug android app there is a debugger by using that you can debug which line of code is working which is not you can debug each line

Comment: Refer to this https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a boolean like `permissionRequested` and set it to `true` if permission request goes through, then consume it in your `onResume`:

`if(permissionRequested){ setupViewPager(); permissionRequested = false; }`

Your viewPager relies on `fragmentmanager`, and `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called before activity is fully resumed which causes odd behavior when adding fragments then.

*Also:*

You should never re-request a denied permission from within `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

If user checks "don't ask again" this will lead to an infinite loop of re-requests (that are invisible to the user), and will mess with your activity. Permission request is an overlaying activity so you'll constantly receive `onPause` `onStart` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i still have the problem that when the app is installed for the first time and opened it doesn't display my songs in the fragments. It only shows when i close the app and then open it again.

Comment: We still don't know how your fragments and recycler adapter looks. Maybe you should always prepare viewpager and create adapter with empty data set, then `notifyDataSetChanged` when you obtain permission?

Comment: I have a MainActivity where i check for user permissions and setup my viewpager/tabs. In the fragments i have arraylists which contain song information and i display that information with a recyclerview adapter. The problem is those adapters are not initialized after i check for permissions, so how can i initialize them when i start/install my app for the first time? There is no problem if i quit the app and then start it, then it loads everything

Comment: Wait i will add a fragment and adapter to my post

Comment: I added a fragment and adapter to my post so it's a bit more detailed. Thanks in advance